# Validation of WPF User Input using MVVM and Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I am building a WPF 4.0 Application using MVVM. The Model is generated using Entity Framework 4.0.
I am using Data binding on the WPF to bind the user input to model properties.

What is the easiest way to validate user input ?
I prefer an approach where I can set the validation rules on the Model rather than on the WPF itself. How can this be done? Any samples are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **BookLibrary** sample application of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com) project shows a MVVM application. It uses the Entity Framework and defines the validation rules on the Model (Entity) classes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i found is taken from [this book](http://www.amazon.ca/Pro-WPF-2010-Presentation-Foundation/dp/1430272058), pages 624-625.

The ViewModel should implement `IDataErrorInfo`

```
private string _newItem;

public string NewItem
        {
            get { return _newItem; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(_newItem, value)) return;
                _newItem = value;
                SendPropertyChanged("NewItem");
            }
        }

public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (propertyName == "NewItem")
                {
                    var valid = NewItem.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);
                    if (!valid)
                        return "NewItem can only contain letters and numbers.";
                }
                return null; 
            }
        }
```

And the view the long version:

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Path="NewItem">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <DataErrorValidationRule></DataErrorValidationRule>
         </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
   </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Or the short version:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

It should create a nice red border around your textbox when rule fails, and you can play around with the error message the way you want, for example bind the error message to a textbox tool tip ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors.aspx)):

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxInError" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
              Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And then just add this to the textbox:

```
Style="{StaticResource TextBoxInError}"
```

Cheers!